# Parameter binding by name through pipeline when some values are empty

Tags: powershell

In my module, I have two functions a 'Get-Data' and 'Add-Data' I'm having trouble passing information between them through the pipeline.

The following simplified code shows my issue.

```
function Get-Data{
    param ($path)
    $out = Import-Csv $path
    Write-Output $out
}
```

The data is the following, notice there are 'gaps' in the data and not every object has all three properties, in fact they cant.  You can only have Name and Color or Name and Fruit.  (In the real code there are many more properties)

```
Name,Color,Fruit
Jim,red,
Kate,,Apple
Bob,green,
Abby,,Banana
```

In the Add-Data function I want to use parameter sets as there are lots of parameters, but only 4 parameter sets possible (two in the simplified code, 'A' and 'B').  This function is exported from the module and I don't want the user to be able to input invalid parameter combinations.

Here is the add-data function:

```
function Add-Data {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(
            Position = 1,
            ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Mandatory = $true
        )]
        [System.String]$Name,

        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName = 'A',
            Position = 2,
            ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Mandatory = $true
        )]
        [System.String]$Color,

        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName = 'B',
            Position = 3,
            ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Mandatory = $true
        )]
        [System.String]$Fruit
    )
    BEGIN{}
    PROCESS{
        Write-Output "$Name $Color $Fruit"
    }
    END{}
}
```

When I pipe one to the other like below:

```
Get-Data -Path c:\some.csv | Add-Data
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Fruit' because it is an empty string
```

I know that I am passing an empty string to the fruit parameter and it's what is causing me the issue, but it's obviously not the behaviour I want.

I'd like the fact that the property is empty to help resolve the parameter set so it only needs Name and Color.

I can't use [AllowNull()] or [AllowEmptyString()] and remove the parameter sets as I expect users to use 'add-data' from the command line and I want 
    help add-data 
to show them the correct params to enter.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why does the parameter being mandatory preclude you from using `[AllowNull()]` and `[AllowEmptyString()]`?

Comment: It doesn't, but I don't want a null value to count towards parameter set resolution.

Comment: `Write-Output $out` -> `$out | % { $Properties = $_.PSObject.Properties; @($Properties | ? { !$_.Value }) | % { $Properties.Remove($_.Name) }; ,$_ }`

Comment: That is a whole lot of punctuation without an explanation :)

Comment: Although if I understand correctly you are saying in the get-Data I should process the object to remove empty properties, this also doesn't work as you then pollute the outgoing pipeline and miss subsequent properties.  If the first object going out is just name,color, the second can't be name,fruit I don't think.

Comment: That's PetSerAl's style. He's usually right, but doesn't bother to post an answer with explanation. What he's doing is iterating through each property of the object, and if it's falsey (like null or empty string) he's removing the property altogether. But you are incorrect in your followup comment; the pipeline does not at all have to be consistent objects.

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks for the help @PetSerAl.

Comment: That is an understandable misconception. It lies in the fact that customobjects default formatting when they reach the end of the pipeline (if they are to be displayed on screen) only accommodates the properties of the first object. It does not remove other properties from additional objects, that's just how `Format-Table` functions when it write to the screen.

Comment: Thanks for that @themadtechnician, it explains a few things in my head.